# C# Xml Node DataTypes

Tags: c#, xml, chartfx

I'm using the following XML for ChartFX: 
http://pastebin.com/sR1N61Ss

The following line is causing the issue:

```
ProductCode="1234568"
```

If I happen to add any alpha characters into the string such as "1235678a" then it it's fine and works.

So my question is, how can I manage what datatypes the nodes are parsed as?

Thanks for reading and any suggestions/solutions would be great.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719879(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I'm looking if you can actually manually manage the datatypes when they are parsed not what datatypes in XML exist.